# Click Internet Explorer IMG/Button with VBA

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I'm trying to "click" on a image that right after a click, execute a function. I tried two things:

```
Private Sub Anbima()

Dim IE As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") IE.Visible =
True IE.navigate
"https://www.anbima.com.br/pt_br/informar/taxas-de-titulos-publicos.htm"
Do Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

IE.document.querySelector("img[name='Consultar']").Click

End Sub
```

But this one gives me Runtime Error 424" error with message "Object Required".

After that I tried to directly run the function:

```
Private Sub Anbima()

Dim IE As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") IE.Visible =
True IE.navigate
"https://www.anbima.com.br/pt_br/informar/taxas-de-titulos-publicos.htm"
Do Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

Call IE.document.parentWindow.execScript("SubmitAction()")

End Sub
```

But this also, give a Runtime Error  '-2147352319 (80020101)': Error 80020101

Here is the HTML code:

```html
<img src="../img/bt_consultar.gif" name="Consultar" onclick="SubmitAction()" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

Would you kindly help me ?

Comment: It is inside an `iframe`. Instead navigate direct to the `iframe` `src` with

    _ie.Navigate2 "https://www.anbima.com.br/informacoes/merc-sec/default.asp"_

then have your page load code and then attempt the click on your element. You may need to trigger the attached onclick. Or use your execScript method.

Comment: @QHarr Thanks ! It worked really fine. Could please tell me where did you find this link: https://www.anbima.com.br/informacoes/merc-sec/default.asp ?

Comment: You could use F12 dev tools to check the source code of the page. Then you could find the link in the `<iframe>` tag: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdl90.png.

Comment: @YuZhou Amazing Yu Zhou ! Thank you !